# Initial conditions of state-space realization

Tags: discrete-signals, linear-systems, state-space

In a discrete-time difference equation (ARX model), the output $y[k]$ is dependent on its past values and inputs, expressed as:

$y[k] = -a_1 y[k-1] - ... - a_N y[k-N] + b_1 u[k-1] + ... + b_M u[k-M]$, with $N \geq M$.

However, when converting the system to an equivalent state-space form, such as the controller canonical form (to use it for example in LQR) it is unclear how the initial conditions are selected.

Do they have to be estimated or can they be based on measurements of the system?